# Need help about usage of "von"

Tags: grammaticality, prefix, person-names

I got confused about the usage of the word. "Von" can be written "Von" if it started in front of the sentence or "v." if abbreviated accroding to The Duden.

What about if you write it in sentences,  "when von Bimd walk" or "when Von Bimd walk" I believe the first one is correct and how do you write the initial, is it "v.B" or "vB" as in von Bimd?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about name prefixes, not about the word *von*.

Those prefixes have to be written as they are stated by the person named. They date back to the time before Germany was united and different states abbreviated/not abbreviated the *Firstname **of** House* differently when the *of House* became proper surnames. You may also encounter *gen.* for *genannt*, which is an older form of the house prefix and also a mixture of *von* and *genannt* respective *v.* and *gen.*

You have to ask the person which of the prefix forms is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant, name prefixes, sorry about wrong meaning question. Anyway, how should i write if i want it as initial?

Comment: The initials should be *FvB* or *FgB*, or simply *vB* or *gB* if there's no first name.

Comment: Ok, so there is no need of "." for initial. I read that in Prussia Military, the "v." was used to distinguished the noble and non-noble. Thank you.

Comment: Possible, but of no relevance today as nobility has being outlawed in Germany in 1918. From there on, only the naming remained.